# How to overcome TZ difference on different servers?

Tags: perl, timezone

We have a few servers in different timezones. We have a table.html that contains dates. 
We want to have correct dates in each server, so we thought that:

```
- we should convert the time on server "A" to unix time. 
- then on server "B" back from unix time to normal time.
```

**Q:** So, how can we convert between normal dates<->unix time (so edit the table.html in-place? )

server "A":

```
cat table.html
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>2014-05-23-12.23.00.000000</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>2014-05-26-17.00.00.000000</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>NA</td></tr>
```

server "B":

```
cat table.html
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>1400840580</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>1401116400</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>NA</td></tr>
```

p.s.: the servers doesn't have the "-d" parameter of the "date" command! maybe perl?
p.s.2: the "X" is censored data, could be anything..
p.s.3: sometimes there isn't any date in the 7th column, then "NA" is written

UPDATE: I tried out an answer:

```
$ cat a.txt 
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>2014-05-23-12.23.00.000000</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>2014-05-26-17.00.00.000000</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>NA</td></tr>
$ 
$ cat b.txt 
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use POSIX;
# Pass the option -i to import from unix time to local time.
# Without the option, export from local time to unix time.
$import = 0;
if (@ARGV && $ARGV[1] eq "-i") {$import = 1}
while (<STDIN>) {
    @F = split m!(<td>.*</td>)!;
    # Field 13 contains a potential date.
    if ($import && $F[13] =~ m!(<td>)([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]*</td>)!) {
    # Import unix time to local time
    ($s,$n,$h,$d,$m,$y,@_tail) = localtime($2);
    $F[13] = sprintf "$1%04d-%02d-%02d-$02d.%02d.%02d$3", $y, $m, $d, $h, $n, $s;
    }
    if (!$import && $F[13] =~ m!(<td>)([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]*</td>)!) {
    # Export local time to unix time
    $t = POSIX.mktime($7, $6, $5, $4, $3, $2);
    $F[13] = "$1$t$8";
    }
    $_ = "@F";
}
$ 
$ 
$ perl b.txt a.txt 
Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[1] in string eq at b.txt line 7.

Use of uninitialized value $F[13] in pattern match (m//) at b.txt line 16, <STDIN> line 1.

Use of uninitialized value $F[13] in pattern match (m//) at b.txt line 16, <STDIN> line 2.

Use of uninitialized value $F[13] in pattern match (m//) at b.txt line 16, <STDIN> line 3.
^C
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend always storing GMT dates, or if this is really inconvenient dates with timezone information. Leaving unspecified dates around isn't a good idea.

If you're stuck with this data format, Perl is a good tool for transforming the local dates into GMT dates and back.

[Parsing HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but it's ok if the input format is highly constrained. In my answer, I'll assume that the table rows are always on a single line, like in your example. If they aren't, you should probably use an actual HTML parser — [`HTML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use POSIX;
# Pass the option -i to import from unix time to local time.
# Without the option, export from local time to unix time.
$import = 0;
if (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] eq "-i") {$import = 1}
while (<STDIN>) {
    @F = split m!(<td>.*</td>)!;
    # Field 13 contains a potential date.
    if ($import && @F >= 13 && $F[13] =~ m!(<td>)([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]*</td>)!) {
        # Import unix time to local time
        ($s,$n,$h,$d,$m,$y,@_tail) = localtime($2);
        $F[13] = sprintf "$1%04d-%02d-%02d-$02d.%02d.%02d$3", $y, $m, $d, $h, $n, $s;
    }
    if (!$import && @F >= 13 && $F[13] =~ m!(<td>)([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]*</td>)!) {
        # Export local time to unix time
        $t = POSIX.mktime($7, $6, $5, $4, $3, $2);
        $F[13] = "$1$t$8";
    }
    $_ = "@F";
}
```

(Warning, untested code!)

Comment: wow, Thanks! It's probably good code, the only problem is that I don't know exactly how can I use it. I did an UPDATE regarding it. Thanks!

Comment: @evachristine Edited.

Answer (score 0):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -MTime::Local -nle 'push @day,$1 if /.*\<td\>(.*)\<\/td\>/;
END {
    for (@day) {
        if (/^\d/) {                                     
            ($y,$m,$d,$h,$mi,$s,@tail) = split("-|\\.",$_);
            print timelocal($s,$mi,$h,$d,$m-1,$y);
        }
    }
}' file
1400822580
1401098400
```

To change the file inplace:

```
$ perl -MTime::Local -i.bak -nle '$date = $1 if /.*\<td\>(.*)\<\/td\>/;
if ($date =~ /^\d/) {
    ($y,$m,$d,$h,$mi,$s,@tail) = split("-|\\.",$date);
    $t = timelocal($s,$mi,$h,$d,$m-1,$y);         
    $_ =~ s/$date/$t/e;
}' file
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>1400822580</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>1401098400</td></tr>
<tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>NA</td></tr>
```

To convert from unixtime to localtime:

```
$ perl -i -nle '$unixtime = $1 if /.*\<td\>(.*)\<\/td\>/;
    if ($unixtime =~ /\d/) {
        ($s,$mi,$h,$d,$m,$y,@tail) = localtime($unixtime);
        $date = sprintf "%04d-%02d-%02d-%02d.%02d.%04d", $y+1900, $m+1, $d, $h, $mi, $s;
        $_ =~ s/$unixtime/$date/e;
    }
' file
```